# How to determine if URL ends in /site-map

Tags: php

I need determine if the current URL ends in /site-map

For example: site.com/site-map

Or

site.com/somedirectory/site-map

Is there a PHP method to pull this value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to check the last 9 characters:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (substr($url,-9)=="/site-map")
```

**edit** to accommodate the url ending with /site-map/ occasionally you could do this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (substr($url,-9)=="/site-map" || substr($url,-10)=="/site-map/")
```

Comment: +1. I'm finding that the URL ends in "/" part of the time. Easy way to account for that?

Comment: Thanks Niklas, I did the || or already. Just wanted to verify there wasn't another way without it.

Comment: @Scott B if you start getting more variations than those 2, you might wanna consider using re then.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `preg_match()` solution.  Likely to be a bit slower than `strpos()` & `substr()`, but more flexible.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (preg_match("/\/site-map$/", $url)) {
  // it ends in /site-map
}
```